# Есть ли View(квадрат) в Android

Tags: android

Должна добавить рандомно квадраты разных цветов(5 столбцов ,а количество строк разное),но количество квадратов =50.Ну и затем сортировать,например красные в первый столб,желтый.....

Comment: квадрат - это любое View у которого width = height

Comment: Пожалуйста не путайте Android с Android Studio

Comment: @Barmaley я вас теперь начинаю понимать, уже пару раз замечал когда вопрос касается только android разработки, но там есть метка на студию)) я даже пару раз редактировал такие вопросы))

Comment: Ну давай такие вопросы нещадно минусовать, кого как, а меня это просто бесит

Comment: @Barmaley, на мой взгляд это не очень правильная практика, критиковать человека можно конечно, даже можно минусовать, но я думаю что сначала лучше просто отредактировать вопрос, и указать на его ошибки, так же указав что если и дальше будет такая проблема то будут идти минуса. На данный момент Liona не просто новый участник, она не знает правил поведения на этом форуме, я вот например тоже таким был ( кстати я теперь понял кто мне вопросы минусовал))  ) но понимание ко мне пришло не сразу))

Comment: я вот кстати не очень понял, почему там опять студия стоит, вроде убирали? или мне показалось?

Comment: Это ТС опять изменил все назад - лишнее свидетельство того, что я был прав минусуя, ТС не понимает разницы между студией и собственно Android'ом. В итоге вопрос звучит примерно так, как если бы вам поставили пустой бокал и спросили - как вам вино нравится? За такое в обычной жизни ведь можно и схлопотать :) - здесь пока все обошлось только виртуальным минусом.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что речь идет о динамическом заполнении layout разными `view` элементами, а квадрат это или треугольник, это уже просто уточнение формы. Вам нужно создать функцию для генерации рандомного числа, и дальше просто заполнять ваш экран тем количеством виджетов которое было сгенерировано рандомно. Вот пример кода:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.btnCreate:
    // Создание LayoutParams c шириной и высотой по содержимому
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        wrapContent, wrapContent);
    // переменная для хранения значения выравнивания
    // по умолчанию пусть будет LEFT
    int btnGravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    // определяем, какой RadioButton "чекнут" и 
    // соответственно заполняем btnGravity 
    switch (rgGravity.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.rbLeft:
      btnGravity = Gravity.LEFT;
      break;
    case R.id.rbCenter:
      btnGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
      break;
    case R.id.rbRight:
      btnGravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
      break;
    }
    // переносим полученное значение выравнивания в LayoutParams
    lParams.gravity = btnGravity;

    // создаем Button, пишем текст и добавляем в LinearLayout
    Button btnNew = new Button(this);
    btnNew.setText(etName.getText().toString());
    llMain.addView(btnNew, lParams);

    break;
  }
}
```

[Первоисточник](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/50-urok-17-sozdanie-view-komponent-v-rabochem-prilozhenii.html)

Но с учетом моего небольшого опыта в области мобильной разработки, я могу ошибаться. Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог :)